# WCF authentication error 'caller was not authenticated by the service'

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I have the following situation:

- Client application is running on a PC that is on a Workgroup.
- WCF service library is hosted under Windows service on a PC that is on a Domain.
- The Windows service is allowed for Everyone access and I have registered the HTTP address using **HTTPCFG** since I have XP.
- Disabled Firewall.
- I'm using **wsHttpBinding**.
- I have added a custom `bindingConfiguration` to a `<security mode="None">`, but it didn't work!
- Tried to add the following code in order to grant access to the service:

  ```
  var objVerifyService = new VerifyClient();
  objVerifyService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "xxx@domain.com";
  objVerifyService.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "111";
  ```

But that returned an error message:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.
>   Authentication Failure

What should I do more? I can't join the client PC to the domain

Answer (score 0):

if you add security mode to none, then is not possible for the service to authenticate, you should set it to Message if you are only using HTTP or set it to TransportWithMessageCredential if you are using HTTPS. Also make sure that both config files are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see the issue from what you've posted, can you post your full config?

You may want to read the [**Codeplex Application Scenarios Guide**](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Application%20Scenarios&referringTitle=Home), which gives you numerous scenarios with a checklist of the code and config you need to get it to work.